# When do I have to set headers and how do I get them?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy, header

I am trying to crawl some information from www.blogabet.com.

In the mean time, I am attending a course at udemy about webcrawling. The author of the course I am enrolled in already gave me the answer to my problem. However, I do not fully understand why I have to do the specific steps he mentioned. You can find his code bellow.

I am asking myself:
1. For which websites do I have to use headers?
2. How do I get the information that I have to provide in the header?
3. How do I get the url he fetches? Basically, I just wanted to fetch: https://blogabet.com/tipsters

Thank you very much :)

```
scrapy shell

from scrapy import Request
url = 'https://blogabet.com/tipsters/?f[language]=all&f[pickType]=all&f[sport]=all&f[sportPercent]=&f[leagues]=all&f[picksOver]=0&f[lastActive]=12&f[bookiesUsed]=null&f[bookiePercent]=&f[order]=followers&f[start]=0'

page = Request(url,
                headers={'Accept': '*/*',
                         'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
                         'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.9,pl;q=0.8,de;q=0.7',
                         'Connection': 'keep-alive',
                         'Host': 'blogabet.com',
                         'Referer': 'https://blogabet.com/tipsters',
                         'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/65.0.3325.181 Safari/537.36',
                         'X-Requested-With': 'XMLHttpRequest'})

fetch(page)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in your network panel when you load that page you can see the XHR and the headers it sends

[image: xhr]
So it looks like he just copied those.

In general you can skip everything except User-Agent and you want to avoid setting Host, Connection and Accept headers unless you know what you're doing.

Comment: Thanks! Can you briefly explain why, for instance, I do not need to set headers for this page http://quotes.toscrape.com/ Likewise, how did he got the long Url? i just used https://blogabet.com/tipsters and that was not working :(

Comment: It's up to the server to decide what headers you need to send. To get the long url, load /tipsters in chrome and look in your network panel for XHRs like in the screenshot